# Click button w/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen similar questions and if there is one that addresses this question please close this as a duplicate.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    $("#findOffice").click(function() {
        $('.register-location').attr('href', function(i, href) {           
            $(this)[0].click();        
       });
    });
```

The idea here being they fill in the input and the submit button is `#findOffice`. After clicking the submit button a dynamic link is created and attached to a button called `.register-location`, this is then inserted into the DOM. I've used the `$(this).[0].click();` successfully before for this purpose but it's not doing anything this time.

My question is, how upon creation of this dynamic link, can I automatically click this new button and move the user along without them having to do so themselves. Open to other ideas if a better solution exists.

Perhaps the link being dynamically inserted into the DOM is the issue?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to redirect the page when the form is submit? Why not just set the `action` attribute on the form and leave the JS out of it? Alternatively, attach the event handler to the submit event of the form, call `preventDefault()` on that and use `window.location.assign('your_new_page.html')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan great suggestions - will check with my dev building this and see why either of those wasn't the route that was taken. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: `this` inside the `attr` function/callback will be `.register-location` - either store `this` first, use `=>` or access directly `$("#findOffice")[0].click()`

Answer (score -1):

This will work with JavaScript, but the Snippets editor here does not allow the window.open method. I'd recommend testing it elsewhere, and it will work there.

```js
var href1 = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp";
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
window.open(href1);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```